# General solution of a wave-like PDE

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, wave-equation

Suppose we have the following PDE:

$$u(x, t) = F(4 x - t) + G(2 x - t),$$

where $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary twice differentiable functions. Let $x \in (- \infty, + \infty)$ and $t > 0$ with ICs

$$u(x, 0) = 0, \quad u_t(x, 0) = f(x).$$

Solve for $u(x, t)$.

**My attempt:** From the first IC we get $F(4 x) = - G(2 x)$ and $F'(4 x) = - G'(2 x)$, where $\frac{d}{d x} F(4 x) = 4 F'(4 x)$ by the chain rule. Then, the second IC gives

$$u_t(x, 0) = - F'(4 x) - G'(2 x) = f(x).$$

Integrate the above equation from $0$ to $x$ yields:

$$\int_0 ^ x f(\tau) \; d \tau = \int_0 ^ x - \frac{d}{d (4 x)} F(4 x) - \frac{d}{d (4 x)} G(2 x) \; d x$$

in which we have $\int_0 ^ x \frac{d}{d (4 x)} F \; d x = \frac{1}{4} F$ and so,

$$\int_0 ^ x f(\tau) \; d \tau = \int_0 ^ x - \frac{1}{4} F(4 x) - \frac{1}{2} G(2 x) \; d x + C,$$

where $C = \frac{1}{4} F(0) + \frac{1}{2} G(0)$.

Thus, we have

\begin{align}
F(4 x) & = 4 \int_0 ^ x f(\tau) \; d \tau - 4 C, \\
G(2 x) & = - 4 \int_0 ^ x f(\tau) \; d \tau + 4 C, \\
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$u(x, 0) = 4 \int_{- x} ^ x f(\tau) \; d \tau.$$

Here I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to figure out the bounds for $t$. I tried the bounds $x - t$ and $- x - t$ but I couldn't verify the solution (I used simply $f(x) = x$).

Would appreciate any help or hints. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're making things too difficult at the end. First, you should have $$u(x,0)=F(4x)+G(2x)=4\int_0^x f(\tau)\,d\tau-4C-4\int_0^x f(\tau)\,d\tau+4C=0$$
in agreement with your IC. Second, if $F(4x)=4\int_0^x f(\tau)\,d\tau-4C$ for all $x$, then $F(4x-t)=?$  The value of $4x-t$ is just another number in the domain of $F$, after all.  (And similarly for $G(2x-t).$)